Amazon SP-API Unauthorized Error: "The access token you provided is revoked, malformed or invalid."
I am trying to interact with the Amazon Selling Partner API (SP-API) to send solicitation requests using the following Flask app. The access token is retrieved successfully, but when making the request to the solicitations endpoint, I receive an Unauthorized error with the message:
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "code": "Unauthorized",
        "details": "The access token you provided is revoked, malformed or invalid.",
        "message": "Access to requested resource is denied."
      }
    ]
  }
}

import boto3
import botocore
from botocore.auth import SigV4Auth
from botocore.awsrequest import AWSRequest
from botocore.credentials import Credentials
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, session, url_for, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'test'

# OAuth credentials
CLIENT_ID = 'amzn1.application-oa2-client.XXXX'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'amzn1.oa2-cs.v1.XXXX'
REDIRECT_URI = 'https://example.com/callback'

AUTHORIZATION_URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa'
TOKEN_URL = 'https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token'
SOLICITATIONS_URL = 'https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/solicitations/v1/orders'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "XXXX"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "XXXX"
AWS_REGION = 'us-east-1'

def get_aws_credentials():
    return Credentials(
        access_key=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secret_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    )

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return '<a href="/login">Login with Amazon</a>'

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    scope = 'sellingpartnerapi::notifications'
    auth_url = f'{AUTHORIZATION_URL}?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&scope={scope}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}'
    return redirect(auth_url)

@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    code = request.args.get('code')
    token_data = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
        'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
    }
    token_response = requests.post(TOKEN_URL, data=token_data)
    token_json = token_response.json()
    session['access_token'] = token_json['access_token']
    session['refresh_token'] = token_json['refresh_token']
    return redirect(url_for('solicitations'))

def get_spapi_access_token():
    refresh_token = session.get('refresh_token')
    token_data = {
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token': refresh_token,
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
    }
    token_response = requests.post(TOKEN_URL, data=token_data)
    token_json = token_response.json()
    return token_json['access_token']

@app.route('/solicitations')
def solicitations():
    access_token = get_spapi_access_token()
    amazon_order_id = 'ORDER ID' # I put a real one
    marketplace_id = 'ATVPDKIKX0DER'
    solicitations_url = f'{SOLICITATIONS_URL}/{amazon_order_id}/solicitations/productReviewAndSellerFeedback?marketplaceIds={marketplace_id}'
    headers = {'x-amz-access-token': access_token, 'content-type': 'application/json'}
    request_obj = AWSRequest(method='POST', url=solicitations_url, headers=headers)
    credentials = get_aws_credentials()
    SigV4Auth(credentials, 'execute-api', AWS_REGION).add_auth(request_obj)
    prepared_request = requests.Request(
        method=request_obj.method,
        url=request_obj.url,
        headers=dict(request_obj.headers),
        data=request_obj.body
    ).prepare()
    response = requests.Session().send(prepared_request)
    return jsonify(response.json()), response.status_code

Why am I getting the "Unauthorized" error even though the access token is successfully retrieved?
Could this be an issue with how the token is being used or signed for the solicitation request?
I’ve checked that my developer profile in Seller Central is approved for the solicitations scope. Any help troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated!
What I Tried:

I followed the OAuth flow to retrieve an access token and successfully stored both the access token and refresh token.
I then used the access token to send a POST request to the solicitations API endpoint (/solicitations/productReviewAndSellerFeedback).
I signed the request using AWS Signature Version 4 with my IAM user credentials and sent the request using the requests library.
What I Expected:
I expected the API to process the solicitation request and return a success response (HTTP 200) indicating that the request was accepted.

Instead, I received an Unauthorized (403) error with the message that the access token was "revoked, malformed, or invalid."
